# How to root ZTE prestige

Tags: rooting

I've looked at XDA and couldn't find anything and nobody will answer my question there. Please let me know if it is possible and if it is, how to do it?

Methods I already tried:

- Framaroot
- Kingoroot
- Towelroot
- Rootmaster
- One Click Root
- root

Answer (score -1):

> Download Cydia Impactor to your desktop – Windows | Mac | Linux
>       32-bit | Linux 64-bit   Extract the package to your desktop
>
> Run the Cydia Impactor tool
>
> On your Android device, enable USB Debugging from Settings > Developer
>   Options
>
> Connect the device to a USB port on your computer
>
> On Windows, you would need to have the USB  drivers for your device
>   installed. If not, you can also use the inbuilt Driver Scan function
>   in the tool to automatically construct and install a driver for your
>   device
>
> Click the Start buton, after making sure that # drop SuperSU su to
>   /system/xbin/su is selected in the dropdown menu
>
> Once done, download and install SuperSU from the Play Store
>
> Enjoy Root access on your Android device

Comment: Your source of info?

Comment: Looks like this was copied-and-pasted from https://dottech.org/138826/how-to-root-any-android-device-with-cydia-impactor-guide/, and a few comments said that it didn't work.